# Select N number of highest values including duplicates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

If I have a table like,

| Names | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| Liam | 50 |
| Jade | 55 |
| John | 55 |
| Pern | 60 |
| Lopa | 20 |

I want to find the top 3 marks but if there are ties I want to include them and the number of people can be more than 3. So this table will become,

| Names | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| Pern | 60 |
| Jade | 55 |
| John | 55 |
| Liam | 50 |

Any suggestions how to take care of the ties part?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8 or later, then the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function can be used here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Names, Marks
FROM cte
WHERE rnk <= 3;
```

### Demo

To do this without using a CTE, just inline it:

```sql
SELECT Names, Marks
FROM
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rnk <= 3;
```

Comment: Can this be done using subqueries instead of cte?

Comment: @Gops61 Yes, check my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Let 'tblMarks' be your table name. Replace @N with your desired value, eg. 3

```
select * from tblMarks where 
Marks between
(SELECT Marks from tblMarks e1 where 
        @N-1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Marks)from tblMarks e2 where e2.Marks > e1.Marks))
        
and
(SELECT Marks from tblMarks e1 where 
        1-1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Marks)from tblMarks e2 where e2.Marks > e1.Marks))
        
order by Marks desc
;
```

---

Explanation:

```
SELECT * from tblMarks e1 where 
        @N-1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Marks)from tblMarks e2 where e2.Marks > e1.Marks) ;
```

Replace @N to 1 to get the first distinct highest value,
@N to 2 to get the second distinct highest value
and so on.

Now simply use Subquery with a between Operator between

1. The Highest Marks and
2. your desired marks

---

So if you give 3 in the first query it will be something like this

```
select * from tblMarks where 
Marks between 50 and 60
order by Marks Desc
```

As 60 is the highest and 50 is the 3rd highest marks.